# Laravel lighthouse paginate without model

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

Is there a way to use the @paginate directive from lighthouse-php without querying data from a model? Let say, i using a third party library to query data using an api or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, such a feature has been added very recently: https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/pull/2232. This PR added support for returning data in a `Paginator` from option `resolver` in `@paginator` directive.

You can provide your own function that resolves the field by directly returning data in a `\Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Paginator` instance.

This is mutually exclusive with `builder` and `model`. Not compatible with `scopes` and builder arguments such as `@eq`.

```
type Query {
  posts: [Post!]! @paginate(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\Posts")
}
```

A custom resolver function may look like the following:

```php
namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
final class Posts
{
    /**
     * @param  null  $root Always null, since this field has no parent.
     * @param  array{}  $args The field arguments passed by the client.
     * @param  \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext  $context Shared between all fields.
     * @param  \GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo  $resolveInfo Metadata for advanced query resolution.
     */
    public function __invoke($root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        //...apply your logic
        return new LengthAwarePaginator([
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'title' => 'Flying teacup found in solar orbit',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'title' => 'What actually is the difference between cookies and biscuits?',
            ],
        ], 2, 15);
    }
}
```

(The docs are currently not getting updated correctly, which is why you probably did not find out about this. I am working on restoring the deployment.)

Comment: Please add details how to implement this in the answer, and not keeping it in the link. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for your fast reply. Would love to have an example here :)